# How can I find $\lim_{x\to0}x^x$ using l'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

How can I find the limit of $x^x$ as $x$ tends to $0$ using l'Hôpital's rule?

I know the derivative of $x^x$ is $\ln(x+1)e^{x\ln{x}}$, but I don't see how to write $x^x$ as a quotient in a form compliant with l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: How about the form

$$x^x = \frac{x^{x-m}}{x^m}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that for $x>0$,
$$x^x=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{1/x}\right).$$
Now evaluate the following limit by using L'Hopital
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(x)}{1/x}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You can write it as $e^{\frac {\ln (x)}{\frac {1}{x}}} $ now both $\ln (x) ,\frac {1}{x} $ tend to |$\infty|$ so you can Apply Lhospital here.